# Be $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ a interval and $f: I \to \mathbb{R} $ a convex function.

Tags: real-analysis

**Be $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ a interval and $f: I \to \mathbb{R} $ a convex function. Prove that if f has maximum value in a point $a \in int I$, then f is a constant function.**

My answer:

> Suppose that f is convex but isn't constant. Taking $a$ like the only point of maximum in I. Notice that how f is convex , we have the followed inequality that says:

\begin{align}
m < a < n \text{  in I} \Rightarrow \frac{f(a) - f(m)}{a - m} \leq \frac{f(n) - f(m)}{n- m} \leq \frac{f(a) - f(n)}{a - n}
\end{align}

> But We had suppose that a was the only point of maximum, which implies in a contradition.

Correct?

Comment: Where is the contradiction? To contradict the fact that $f(a)$ is the maximum would require finding a real $b \in I$ so that $f(b)>f(a)$.

Comment: Also, the problem doesn't say $a$ is the only value of $x$ where $f(x)$ is a maximum, just that $f(a)$ is the maximum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us prove it by contradiction.

In order to do so, we shall assume that $f$ is not constant.

If $a\in I$ is a local maximum, there exists a neighborhood $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ such that $f$ is increasing in $(a-\delta,a)$ and $f$ is decreasing in $(a,a+\delta)$.

Take $x_{1}\in(a-\delta,a)$ and $x_{2}\in(a,a+\delta)$. Hence we can say that $f(x_{1}) < f(a)$ and $f(x_{2}) < f(a)$.

On the other hand, given that $f$ is convex, we should have
\begin{align*}
f(\lambda x_{1} + (1-\lambda)x_{2})\leq \lambda f(x_{1}) + (1-\lambda)f(x_{2})
\end{align*}

Given that $a\in[x_{1},x_{2}]$, there is some $\lambda_{0}$ such that $a = \lambda_{0}x_{1} + (1-\lambda_{0})x_{2}$. Thus we have that
\begin{align*}
f(a) \leq \lambda_{0}f(x_{1}) + (1-\lambda_{0})f(x_{2})
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we also have that
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{0}f(x_{1}) + (1-\lambda_{0})f(x_{2}) < \lambda_{0}f(a) + (1 - \lambda_{0})f(a) = f(a)
\end{align*}
which contradicts our previous claim.

Therefore $f$ must be constant, and we are done.

Comment: A function is *not* necessarily increasing/decreasing in a neighborhood of a local maximum.

Comment: There is an additional result which claims that convex functions are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof works ! but you have to say more. Starting with the double inequality you stated in your post, we have: $f(a) \ge f(m)$, and $f(a) \ge f(n)$ since $f(a)$ is the max value. Furthermore, $a - m > 0$ and $a - n < 0$. Thus $\dfrac{f(a) - f(m)}{a-m} \ge 0$, and $\dfrac{f(a) - f(n)}{a-n} \le 0$. So putting together: $0 \le \dfrac{f(m) - f(n)}{m-n} \le 0\implies \dfrac{f(m) - f(n)}{m-n} = 0\implies f(m) = f(n)=f(a)$. This means for any $m, n \in I$ and $m \neq n$, $f(m) = f(n)=f(a)$. Thus $f$ must be constant and this constant is $f(a)$.